# how to check for positive multiples of 2 using modulus operator in an if loop

Tags: c++11, if-statement, visual-c++, modulo

I was trying to use the mod % operator in C++ but it shows the error *Expression is not assignable*

```
int i = 0;
    cin>>i;
//    for (i; i < 25; i++) {
        if (i < 25 && i % 2 = 0) {
            cout<<"test"<<i;
        } else {
            cout<<"test2"<<i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    int i = 0;
    cin>>i;
//    for (i; i < 25; i++) {
        if (i < 25 && i % 2 == 0) {
            cout<<"test"<<i;
        } else {
            cout<<"test2"<<i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i%2=0 changed i%2==0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).